# Display message alert for Session expired

Tags: javascript, session-timeout

How to show alert message when session.timeout occurs?
after 5 minutes i want to expire my page and redirect to login page. after redirecting i want to show user that their session has expired.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (session["MySessionName"] == null)
{
 .. show message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're after 5 minutes of inactivity.

```
function doLogout() {
    window.location.href="/logout?reason=timeout"
}

window.setTimeout(doLogout(), 300000)
```

Set your desired timeout and then logout, passing some form of parameter to the logout-mechanism so that the message can be displayed.

Another option would be to poll for the session-cookie. The approach is similar but instead of doing the logout directly, check if the cookie is still alive and if it is start a new timer. For that to work, you will have to set the expiration of you session to the wished for value.

As a side note, for accessability reasons you should really warn the user before terminating their session and offer a way to renew the session.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to ping your server at few seconds for session expiry.

Algo:

1. Right async call to server
2. Receive the response with true/false
3. show alert accordingly.

   ```
   $return = array("status"=>1);
   if($_SESSION['ANY_SESSION_VAR']){
       $return = array("status"=>0);
   }

   die(json_encode($return);
   ```

   http://jsfiddle.net/2CgkV/1/